# How to change directories to a different hard drive using Ubuntu on WSL?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have just started learning bash. I am fighting a bit with this simple problem:

> Please write EXACTLY the command that you would use to get to hard drive F:, folder Fiddler.

Side question: What do each of these 4 words mean? If I type `ls` in bash, I get this:

```
examples.desktop itnetworktest Desktop Videos
```

I installed cygwin, and then bash for Windows 10. I need to learn Linux bash for college.

Answer (score 3):

**Primary question**

The hard drives labelled `C:/`, `D:/` etc in Windows should be mounted as `c`, `d` etc either in a `/mnt` directory, or one called `/cygdrive`, I believe, depending on your setup. If the folder you are looking for is located at  `F:/fiddler` in Windows, it should be at either `/mnt/f/fiddler` or `/cygdrive/f/fiddler` when accessed from Linux.

So you would be able to get there with `cd /mnt/f/fiddler` or `cd /cygdrive/f/fiddler`.

**Side question**

The command `ls` in bash (and AFAIK also in Windows) will list ('LiSt') all the files and directories located in the current directory. It's like if you opened your directory in a graphical file explorer program like Windows Explorer, and see a little icon & the name for every file & directory at the current location.

So if you execute the command `ls` and it returns `examples.desktop itnetworktest Desktop Videos`, that means that in the current directory (presumably your home folder?), there are four files/directories: one called `examples.desktop` (presumably a file), one called `itnetworktest` (presumably a file), one called `Desktop` (presumably a directory) and one called `Videos` (presumably a directory).

Note that `ls` as-is provides *only* the names and nothing more. You can instead use it with an additional option, as `ls -la`, to see a little more info (on many systems, the shorter 'alias' command `ll` can also be used instead of the full `ls -la` for the same effect). This way of displaying might be laid out slightly more similar to the graphical file browsers you're used to.

**PS**

Generally, when you have two separate questions that are not directly related, it is good practice to post both separately, as distinct questions. That helps to keep the site organized, makes it easier for people to find your question, and makes it clearer what someone can expect to find when they click on the title. It probably also makes your questions more accessible - someone who can help with one question but not the other might choose not to engage at all if they feel they cannot 'fully' answer your question as posed, if you combine two questions into one post.